# MySQL 8.0 cannot insert NULL values to date field

Tags: mysql, null

I'm trying to insert a data from file to MYSQL 8.0 using the InnoDB engine.

I'm using this query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/item_new_1_4.dat'
INTO TABLE Item FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|';
```

I'm getting an error message:

```
ERROR 1292 (22007) at line 1: Incorrect date value: 'NULL' for column 'i_rec_end_date' at row 1
```

The table was created by this query:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item(
    i_item_sk integer ,
    i_item_id char(16) NOT NULL,
    i_rec_start_date date,
    i_rec_end_date date,
    i_item_desc varchar(200),
    i_current_price decimal(7,2),
    i_wholesale_cost decimal (7,2),
    i_brand_id integer,
    i_brand char(50),
    i_class_id integer default ,
    i_class char(50),
    i_category_id integer,
    i_category char(50),
    i_manufact_id integer,
    i_manufact char(50),
    i_size char(20),
    i_formulation char(20),
    i_color char(20),
    i_units char(10),
    i_container char(10),
    i_manager_id integer,
    i_product_name char(50),
    PRIMARY KEY (i_item_sk)
);
```

The data at line 1 is:

```
1|AAAAAAAABAAAAAAA|1997-10-27|NULL|Powers will not get influences. Electoral ports should show low, annual chains. Now young visitors may pose now however final pages. Bitterly right children suit increasing, leading el|27.02|23.23|5003002|exportischolar #2|3|pop|5|Music|52|ableanti|N/A|3663peru009490160959|spring|Tsp|Unknown|6|ought|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because MySQL is actually trying to insert the literal string 'NULL' into a DATE column, not the actual value `NULL`.

Your choices are:

- Global search for `|NULL|` in your file and replace with `||`
- Change your `LOAD DATA` statement to deal with it:

> LOAD DATA INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/item_new_1_4.dat' INTO TABLE
>   Item FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
>       (i_item_sk integer ,
>                                       i_item_id,
>                                       i_rec_start_date,
>                                       @i_rec_end_date,
>                                       i_item_desc,
>                                       i_current_price,
>                                       i_wholesale_cost,
>                                       i_brand_id,
>                                       i_brand,
>                                       i_class_id,
>                                       i_class,
>                                       i_category_id,
>                                       i_category,
>                                       i_manufact_id,
>                                       i_manufact,
>                                       i_size,
>                                       i_formulation,
>                                       i_color,
>                                       i_units,
>                                       i_container,
>                                       i_manager_id,
>                                       i_product_name )  SET
>       i_rec_end_date = nullif(@i_rec_end_date,'NULL');

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:  See Phil's Answer

Plan B:

`SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode';`

Then think about changing the setting(s) relating to dates before doing the `LOAD`.  Perhaps change it back after cleaning up the data.

Plan C:

`LOAD` into a separate table with a `VARCHAR` for that column.  Then populate the 'real' table from it, fixing the `"NULL"` (or whatever) to whatever.  Ditto for any other columns that need cleansing.

Plan D:  (Shorter than C, but not as powerful for cleansing):

Use @variables in the `LOAD`, plus `SET` with an expression to set the column with whatever you want instead of the null.